# update error 80072efe

Tags: 8.1, update, nokia-lumia-720

When I check for updates, my phone says:

> We are currently unable to check for updates.(80072efe).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That error code normally indicates `ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED` i.e. The connection with the server has been terminated. This *might* be due to a poor network/WiFi reception, either locally, or between you and the servers.

It may be worth trying again later, when there's a better connection; and if this doesn't work, it might be worth backing everything up and trying a hard reset of the phone.